# Free DayView Calendar for WPF?

Tags: wpf

Is there a free DayView Calendar for WPF like this one?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/Calendardayview.aspx

Thanks in advance! Cheers from Argentina!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at these articles on Code Project

- [Creating an Outlook Calendar Using WPF (Part 1)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30329/Creating-an-Outlook-Calendar-using-WPF-Part-1)
- [Creating an Outlook Calendar Using WPF (Part 2)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30881/Creating-an-Outlook-Calendar-Using-WPF-Part-2)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30881/Creating-an-Outlook-Calendar-Using-WPF-Part-2 Not a complete one. many users arise question but the author not responded. Have you implemented this control @pabloide86?

Answer (score 0):

Datepickers are a sore point among WPF users still. There's no official standard date picker in the framework yet, and definitely not something like you're looking for.

That said, it's certainly possible to implement using ListView or a DataGrid with some heavy template customization. If you're interested in a starting direction, post a comment to me and I'll update my answer if you want to go the homebrew route.